# Using Google Play Store to push out updates to a "device owner" app

Tags: android

We have an Android app that we'd like to run on thousands of identical tablets that we will own and rent to our customers. The app runs in a sort of "kiosk mode" (we use app pinning, in the parlance of this page: https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html). We're also, at present, configuring our app as the device owner using `adb shell dpm set-device-owner ...`.

We have two goals here:

1. Be able to push updates to the app out to all our devices without any user interaction on each device.
2. Reduce the manual configuration of each new device when we unbox it and set it up as much as possible.

Can we use Google Play Store to push app updates out? I had in mind that we'd use the Alpha or Beta release for this and never actually publish the app for others to install. Using Google Play Store of course requires a Google Account to be added to the device, and once we do that, I fear our options for using a device owner app are limited, not to mention the fact that adding that Google Account may not be able to be scripted using adb or similar. We'd like to avoid manually adding the Google Account if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the Google Play sandbox is still very consumer app oriented. However, the Play EMM API and Managed Google Play have some capabilities around distributing apps: https://developers.google.com/android/work/distribute

Their EMM documentation covers provisioning as well via either a device-driven flow (using nfc) or a user driven flow (using a google account): https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices

Alternatively you could look at 3rd party MDM solutions or use a platform built for enterprise mobile deployment like Mason: http://bymason.com

Mason allows you to create a custom Android OS in a just a few minutes (kiosk mode app, disable camera/sms, remove apps and settings, etc). Applications can be bundled and versioned along with the operating system or deployed independently. Mason supports background app and os updates 100% controlled and configured by you.

You can order large volumes devices from Mason with your OS and apps preloaded on them as well.

Feel free to ping me directly: `dylan @ bymason.com`

**Big Disclaimer: I work for Mason**

Comment: Could explain what exactly, technically, legally, or feature-wise, is broken about using Google Play (consumer) for this? We'd go the EMM route but that also doesn't look appropriate. I'm not sure we fit the mould as an EMM solution provider.

Comment: I agree, EMM may be overkill, all depending on your use case. If I remember correctly the default behavior for app pinning you can exit the application by holding the home and recents buttons. EMM could give you more control over that “kiosk” experience.

Comment: It can vary greatly depending on your use case, however, I can touch on a few examples: 
- Limited to deploying via alpha or beta releases in the play store. 
- I’m not 100% if alpha/beta updates can be installed in the background or if it requires user interaction. 
- Requires a Google account on every device you deploy. 
- Carrier/Manufacture OS updates could be pushed to your device or prompt users to install updates. 

Again could vary depending on your use case. If industry regulation is not a problem (healthcare/transportation), you may be OK

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one kiosk mode device owner app.  Since it was a system app, we just had it use the system ability to do silent installs, self hosted the updates and checked for updates on a regular schedule.  No configuration needed.  I think you're more likely to hit legal problems than anything else-  are you really using high end tablets that have legal licenses to Google Play for a kiosk mode app?  Or are you using the cheap tablets from China?  Remember that Google Play is not a free app-  there's a licensing fee and usage agreements you have to sign to have the right to distribute it.  The cheap tablets tend to just illegally sideload it, or not have it.

Advantages to doing it ourselves:  we had absolute control over rollout, there was no company saying when we could send updates, and no way for the user to reject/not download an update.  As you scale you could have even used more intelligence, and done rolling updates to the fleet via push notification.

Comment: Thanks. The tablet's a branded one with a legit Google Play on it. Could you expand on "use the system ability to do silent installs"? Did you programmatically reinstall the app using the package manager? Did you have to write a separate updater app, or did the app update itself?

Comment: There is a permission a system app can get to install an app without popping up a dialog box. We used that. We did go with a 2nd app to update is, but not because it wasn't possible to do in one app. We used two so we could restart the main app when installation was done.